# Can someone help vectorise this matlab loop?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

i am trying to learn how to vectorise matlab loops, so im just doing a few small examples.

here is the standard loop i am trying to vectorise:

```
function output = moving_avg(input, N)
    output = [];
    for n = N:length(input) % iterate over y vector
        summation = 0;
            for ii = n-(N-1):n % iterate over x vector N times
                summation += input(ii);
            endfor
        output(n) = summation/N;
    endfor 
endfunction
```

i have been able to vectorise one loop, but cant work out what to do with the second loop. here is where i have got to so far:

```
function output = moving_avg(input, N)
    output = [];
    for n = N:length(input) % iterate over y vector
        output(n) = mean(input(n-(N-1):n));
    endfor 
endfunction
```

can someone help me simplify it further?

**EDIT:**
the input is just a one dimensional vector and probably maximum 100 data points. N is a single integer, less than the size of the input (typically probably around 5)

i don't actually intend to use it for any particular application, it was just a simple nested loop that i thought would be good to use to learn about vectorisation..

Comment: What are the dimensions of inputs? What datasizes are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab as a language does this type of operation poorly - you will always require an outside O(N) loop/operation involving at minimum O(K) copies which will not be worth it in performance to vectorize further because matlab is a heavy weight language.  Instead, consider using the 
[filter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#bt_vs4t-2_1) function where these things are typically implemented in C which makes that type of operation nearly free.

Comment: thanks for your response, like i said, i am not necessarily interested in this particular function per-se, just wanted to get my head around vectorising loops in matlab

Comment: ah,  had that post crafted up before you mentioned that.  This is not a good example to work with for vectoriztion.  Instead focus on examples with bsxfun which will definitely show you much more interesting examples.

And if you really want to go wild on vectorization, take a look at einstein summation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Matlab might not have first class support for it but numpy does: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

In addition to bsxfun, it's one of the most interesting and performance improving functions I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are performing [`convolution operation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) there. So, just use [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) -

```
output = zeros(size(input1))
output(N:end) = conv(input1,ones(1,N),'valid')./N
```

Please note that I have replaced the variable name `input` with `input1`, as `input` is already used as the name of a built-in function in MATLAB, so it's a good practice to avoid such *conflicts*.

---

**Generic case:** For a general case scenario, you can look into [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create such groups and then choose your operation that you intend to perform at the final stage. Here's how such a code would look like for sliding/moving average operation -

```
%// Create groups of indices for each sliding interval of length N
idx = bsxfun(@plus,[1:N]',[0:numel(input1)-N])  %//'

%// Index into input1 with those indices to get grouped elements from it along columns
input1_indexed = input1(idx)

%// Finally, choose the operation you intend to perform and apply along the
%// columns. In this case, you are doing average, so use mean(...,1).
output = mean(input1_indexed,1)
%// Also pre-append with zeros if intended to match up with the expected output
```

Answer (score 0):

For a sliding average, you can use [`cumsum`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) to minimize the number of operations:

```
x = randi(10,1,10);                      %// example input
N = 3;                                   %// window length
y = cumsum(x);                           %// compute cumulative sum of x
z = zeros(size(x));                      %// initiallize result to zeros
z(N:end) = (y(N:end)-[0 y(1:end-N)])/N;  %// compute order N difference of cumulative sum
```

Comment: clever but more like dynamic programming than vectorization.  And what about the results on the ends and beginning?  most of the time people want those too :-)!

Comment: @JasonNewton I removed the results on the ends because the code in the original post did so. But it would be very easy to include them